# In your web app, when uploading files to S3, is it safe to upload them directly to S3 from the client side?

Tags: file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my app, the users will upload a large number of image files. It's a photo hosting website. For this situation, I thought of directly uploading the files to amazon s3 from the client side. Is this safe? Im concerned about security. Should I simply upload the files to my server and then send it to s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely do the upload via your own server, which allows you to control who gets to upload what. Many web applications have modules which simplify that.
Never take user input (and even less so uploads) for what they seem to be... You need to be able to do sanity checks, and for any sort of binary probably malware checks too.

Comment: this isn't the case. S3 has a feature to create what is called pre-signed urls for this use case.

Comment: Pre signed urls don’t prevent you from restricting who can upload. Obviously you should validate all your inputs before processing but storing to memory on your own server disk or s3 isn’t different

Answer (score 5):

Best practice is to allow the client application to upload to S3 directly.

Allowing direct uploads to s3 allows massive concurrency and reduced infrastructure costs. Some infrastructure providers Heroku, for example, don't allow connections to last more than 30seconds. This limitation can make hosting images much more difficult.

S3 allows uploading through a feature called [pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). Your backend is still responsible for authenticating the user; it then generates a unique URL that client application can then use for direct upload.

Answer (score -1):

You can use aws cognito to authenticate and authorize the user. Then from the client side using amplify or aws sdk, you can login and upload files directly to s3